How can I find out with APT to which package a purely virtual package refers?
How can I find out with APT to which package it refers?
host# apt-get install xvnc4viewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package xvnc4viewer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xvnc4viewer' has no installation candidate
host# 
host# 
host# 
host# apt-cache show xvnc4viewer
N: Can't select versions from package 'xvnc4viewer' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
host# 


This is one of the circumstances where apt can’t help you, because the package has been removed from the repositories. You can find this out using the package tracker; this will tell you that the package came from the vnc4 source package, and just before it was removed, was a transitional package depending on tigervnc-viewer.
The reason apt still knows about it (and thinks it’s a virtual package) is that x2vnc and epoptes still mention it.
